# Live jQuery editing in browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I would like to test some jQuery live on the page. I'm trying to use Chrome's developer tools console for this. Is it possible?

For example, I have a div on the live page with class="foo":

```
 <div class="foo">Some content</div>
```

So, in the inspector, I've opened the sources tab and clicked on an existing .js script that is active on the page. I've scrolled to the bottom of that script and inserted this jQuery:

```
jQuery('.foo').hide();
```

Why does it not hide the foo div?

Answer (score 4):

You should paste that into the console. Adding it to the actual script won't do you any good.

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks. I was trying to do the same as I do with css tweaks :) I can directly alter the dom via css edits on the source tab css files. Thought I should be able to do the same on .js files.